# Looking for a pi-compatible thermometer for brewing

Tags: sensor

I would like to use my Raspberry Pi to monitor my fermentation temperature.  I would like a thermometer I can attach to the side of the carboy and wire up to the Raspberry from a few feet away.

For bonus points, I would like to place multiple sensors on the carboy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Nice idea. A quick Google reveals [a few thermostats/thermometers that work fine](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/03/raspberry-pi-1-wire-digital-thermometer-sensor/) with the Raspberry Pi,  but there are also [several questions on here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=thermostat) that offer solutions already.

Comment: Okay, but all of these sensors seem to measure the air temperature, or are submersible in liquid.  I'm looking for something that I can attach/glue to the outside of a carboy to measure the temperature of the glass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the thermal sensor @Jivings suggested and some thermal grease . http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/03/raspberry-pi-1-wire-digital-thermometer-sensor/ + http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=thermal+paste

Attach the sensor to the carboy with some thermal grease, to ensure good thermal conductivity, and glue/tape it to keep it in place.

You can even hook multiple up easily by running single wires for GND and 3.3v around the carboy.

Comment: These DS18B20[+ = lead free] temperature sensors are a good choice. They are quite cheap, deliver the data in digital format, and using multiple of them on the same wire and averaging the values will give a pretty precise reading.

Answer (score 2):

Adafruit sells a [waterproof temperature sensor](http://www.adafruit.com/products/381) that would work.  They also have a related [tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/).

Answer (score 1):

I use a TEMPer USB Thermometer with my Pi, they are less than $10. I guess you could use as many as you want with a hub and attach them with a thermal epoxy.

Search for 'temper pi' for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This might just be useful, check it out: http://brewpi.com/